# Showing 500 (Internal Server Error) using backbone.js with slim.php when only adding new model

Tags: backbone.js

I got this code from https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar as I am trying to learn backbone.js. When I am trying to add new model to database using slim.php, it is showing 500 (Internal Server Error). But when I am trying to fetch, update, delete its working good. Why it is showing error only on adding ?

Plz help me, Thanks.

```
    window.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function () {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            "click .save"   : "beforeSave",
            "click .delete" : "deleteWine"

        },

        beforeSave: function () {
            var self = this;
            var check = this.model.validateAll();
            if (check.isValid === false) {
                utils.displayValidationErrors(check.messages);
                return false;
            }

            // Upload picture file if a new file was dropped in the drop area
            if (this.pictureFile) {
                this.model.set("picture", this.pictureFile.name);
                utils.uploadFile(this.pictureFile,
                    function () {
                        self.saveWine();
                    }
                );
            } else {
                this.saveWine();
            }
            return false;
        },

        saveWine: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.model.save(null, {
                success: function (model) {
                    self.render();
                    app.navigate('wines/' + model.id, false);
                    utils.showAlert('Success!', 'Wine saved successfully', 'alert-success');
                },
                error: function () {
                    utils.showAlert('Error', 'An error occurred while trying to add this item', 'alert-error');
                }
            });
        },

        deleteWine: function () {
            this.model.destroy({
                success: function () {
                    alert('Wine deleted successfully');
                    window.history.back();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: well Internal server error means that an internal server error has occurred (aka your server just went down), so the error originates from your server. So can you post the code for you slim server, especially the code concerning ADDING items?

Comment: Also would be interesting to see the _500 error log_

Comment: I am working on localhost and the code obtained from this url https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar.  The same code is generating 500 error while only adding a new model to database in the localhost. Remaining all update, delete, fetch are working fine. The code part I already posted above. I am able to view the error on the browser's console. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In your /tutorial/api directory; open index.php and look for the first line in the function addWine():

error_log('addWine\n', 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');

Comment that line:

//error_log('addWine\n', 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');

This should solve your problem, it certainly did mine.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer -- finally solved the issue for me after lots of unnecessary troubleshooting.